# how to test void javascript functions using jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to test void javascript function (a function that does not return anything) using jest framework? Can you please provide an example for the same?

```
/**
 * this function is used to toggle the input type password field
 * @param element {DOMElement} - field to be toggled
 */
export const togglePassword = (element) => {
    const type = element.getAttribute('type');
    if (type === 'text') {
        element.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    } else {
        element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    }
}
```

How can we test such type of functions?

Comment: test what they return? they return `undefined`?

Comment: A function that doesn't return a value must have side effects or it's pointless; side effects such as changing the state of an object passed to it, or doing something in the environment. So if the function isn't pointless, test for its side-effects. If you gave actual examples, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: that's a UI test where you need to check that the element attribute "type" is set accordingly...

Answer (score 27):

The best way to test a void function is by mocking the behavior of its dependencies.

```
// module being tested
import sideEffect from 'some-module';

export default function () {
    sideEffect();
}
```

Using file mocking and function expectations, you can assert that the function called the other module as expected:

```
import hasSideEffect from './hasSideEffect';
import sideEffect from 'some-module';

jest.mock('some-module');

test('calls sideEffect', () => {
    hasSideEffect();

    expect(sideEffect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(sideEffect).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```